# Whenever someone casts an enchant on one of my creatures, do I control that enchantment?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I control Genesis Hydra, then an opponent casts Claustrophobia onto Genesis Hydra, do I control Claustrophobia?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That other question is about casting an aura on your creature, then you lose control of that creature. This question is about casting an aura on a creatura you don't control.

Comment: This question is really a **subset of** the other.

Comment: Both questions are basically "If you cast (past tense) an Aura Enchantment on a creature and your opponent controls the creature, who controls the enchantment?"

Comment: @ikegami You read my comment exactly backwards. This question ⊂ other question. Other question ⊄ this question.

Comment: They are both asking the same thing: if my enchantment is on my opponent's creature, who controls the enchantment. One has the enchantment enter and then the creature change control, and the other has the enchantment enter on a creature already controlled by the opponent, but they are essentially the same problem and they have the same answer for the same reason.

Comment: @ikegami Please don't use your dupe hammer to override the community. Your gold badge does not make you the final arbiter of what should be closed.

Comment: You absolutely can choose not to use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17959/discussion-between-murgatroid99-and-ikegami).

Comment: (Sorry, I didn't know that closing a question as a duplicate didn't remove it from search results.)

Comment: Wow, I read y'all's chat thread, and it has given me hope for humanity!

Answer (score 4):

You don't control Claustrophobia. Permanents enter the battlefield under the control of the controller of the spell, unless something else is explicitly stated.

For permanent spells:

> 608.3. If the object that’s resolving is a permanent spell, its resolution involves a single step (unless it’s an Aura). The spell
>   card becomes a permanent and is put onto the battlefield under the
>   control of the spell’s controller.

For other spells or abilities:

> 110.2a If an effect instructs a player to put an object onto the battlefield, that object enters the battlefield under that player’s
>   control unless the effect states otherwise.

Comment: 110.2a directly addresses this issue and seems sufficient to me. It also seems to be the more fundamental and basic rule, which I'd argue is backed up by the fact that it appears earlier. 608.3 explicitly mentions an exception for Auras, and although that's not relevant, it does confuse things and also does not cover everything that 110.2a covers. I'd suggest using only 110.2a here.

Comment: @KRyan a permanent spell being put in the battlefield as the last step of it resolving is an effect, but is not something obvious. It is better to quote both rules so new players are not confused.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not control Claustrophobia. As with all permanents, Auras come into play under the control of the person who cast the spell that became the permanent. It doesn't matter who controls the permanent that the Aura is enchanting.

> A permanent’s controller is whoever put it into play unless the spell or ability that put the permanent into play states otherwise. Other effects can later change a permanent’s controller.